# create symbolic link to already created folder

Tags: linux

I have already created the folder `/var/dir` as root. I want to symlink another directory `/home/kute/test` to `/var/dir` - and this have to run as 'kute' user.

But I am getting

> /home/kute/test --> /var/dir/test

instead of getting

> /home/kute/test --> /var/dir

Answer (score 3):

What command did you use?

```
ln -s /home/kute/test /var/dir
```

If you want `/var/dir` to be the link, you have to remove/rename the existing directory first. It's not possible to have a directory and a link of the same name.

Comment: @Kute Your mistake is to create that directory. Don't! Just create the link.

Comment: But I cant create/move the directory /var/dir as 'kute' user. That is why I have created /var/dir as root and then tried to symlink as 'kute' user